# SQL Server calendar zero point '1900-01-01 00:00:00' is fixed?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Is this date '1900-01-01 00:00:00', which is zero point in SQL Server's calendar, fixed for good or it is dynamic according to century or system settings or something else?

Comment: That year isn't going to occur again — it's fixed.  The basis didn't change when the millennium rolled around (whichever year you take as the start of the new millennium) — it's fixed.

Comment: If you're asking whether `cast(0 as datetime)` is ever going to produce anything other than `01/01/1900 00:00:00`, then no, I can see no way a breaking change of this magnitude would happen.

Comment: Maybe in 7980 years, Microsoft might change the datetime structure. Then, you will have to change your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime type stores a range of dates and times internally as two integers (date part and time part), with the date part holding the number of days before or after 01-01-1900 (negative values for before).

If Microsoft were to change the meaning of 0 (being 01-01-1900) in a future release, it would invalidate the data being stored in the table (as users would see different dates being displayed) - so it will not happen.

If they did need to change the datetime type, they would bring out a new type (say datetime3), but datetime would still be there - for backwards compatibility.

Comment: For the datetime type, it's the number of milliseconds since midnight, with a precision of 3 milliseconds. That's why, if you don't specify the time, it defaults to midnight...